# Minimal embedding of real projective surface into $S^4$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, projective-space, minimal-surfaces

I'm reading a paper, and one result was quoted there:

There is a minimal embedding of $\mathbb {RP}^2$ into $S^4$, and the corresponding volume is 6$\pi$.

Any reference is welcomed. And thanks for anyone who could offer help in advance.

(According to the paper, the embedding is called Veronese surface. I googled it that the answer was not satisfactoring. Sorry that I forget to mention it in the beginning)

Comment: Also, could you tell us the name of the paper? I'd like to take a look at it.

Comment: P.Li and Yau, A New Conformal Invariant and Its Applications 
to the Willmore Conjecture and the First Eigenvalue 
of Compact Surfaces,   Corollary 5 on page 15.

Comment: You can search Veronese embedding and should find the explicit embedding.

Comment: I did, but only found a map from $RP^2$ to $RP^5$. So I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Comment: Check page 224 of the Handbook of Differential Geometry, Volume 1. [Google link](https://books.google.com/books?id=U2BIz8NNksYC&pg=PA224&lpg=PA224&dq=veronese+surface+minimal&source=bl&ots=OH8jRh6QZp&sig=ACfU3U3FD-22g8YSuVxPVMpVhgwsz5snFw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib8pCZ56DqAhXDUs0KHZekDGUQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=veronese%20surface%20minimal&f=false) for the relevant page. (mentioning the Veronese embedding was relevant, actually)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an answer, but too long for a comment. I do know about an embedding, but I learned this in a class and I have no idea where the professor took that from. In any case, here it is: consider $$ V = \{ T\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3 \mid T^\top = T \mbox{ and }\,{\rm tr}(T) = 0  \}.$$It is easy to see that $V$ is a vector space and $\dim V = 5$. The map $(T,S)\mapsto {\rm tr}(TS)$ defines an inner product on $V$. Now define $\Phi\colon \Bbb R P^2 \to V$ by $$\Phi(\Bbb R p) = \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\,{\rm pr}_{\Bbb R p, 0},$$where ${\rm pr}_{\Bbb Rp}\colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ denotes the projection onto the line $\Bbb R p$ (here $p \in \Bbb R^3\setminus \{0\}$, of course), and for linear $T \colon \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$, $T_0 = T - ({\rm tr}(T)/3){\rm Id}_{\Bbb R^3}$ denotes the traceless part of $T$. It turns out that $\Phi$ is a smooth embedding, and the image $\Phi[\Bbb R P^2]$ is contained in the unit sphere of $V$ (the coefficient $\sqrt{3/2}$ is meant to rescale the radius of the sphere to $1$), which is a $\Bbb S^4$. Maybe this is what you want?

Comment: It is mot clear that the area is $6\pi$ though. What is $T^\top$?

Comment: $T^\top$ is stands for the transpose/adjoint of $T$, but I do agree that it is not clear what the area is (and to be honest, being a minimal embedding is not entirely clear to me either). That's why I said it was not quite an answer, but OP can see if this makes sense in the context of the paper, and maybe get started.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I checked what you said, and it looks good. But still such an embedding is hard to do analysis on. I tried, but couldn give coordinates to such an embedding.

Comment: Yes, coordinates are awkward. One good way to proceed would be to compute the derivative $T_L(\Bbb R P^2) \to V$ by using the isomorphism $T_L(\Bbb R P^2) = {\rm Hom}(L,L^\perp)$. See Section 2.3 [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/~piccione/Downloads/NotasXIEscola.pdf) and make $k=1$ everywhere.

Comment: Cool. I'll try it.